# Mock method in test file from different directory python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

I am attempting to mock a method and running into issues with `mock` actually overwriting it.

app/tests/test_file.py <- contains the the unit test, currently using:

```
@mock.patch('app.method', return_value='foo')
def test(self, thing):
    ...
    do some stuff with app/main/server.py 
    and get its response, assert a few values
    ...
    assert 'foo' is in return value of some stuff
```

The method being mocked is being called by another file that server.py is calling.

- app/main/server.py  <- what the unit test is actually interacting with
- app/main/route.py  <- where method being mocked is called
- app/main/thing.py  <- contains method to be mocked

This is with python 2.7 and each package has an init file.  The parent folder (app) contains imports for every class and method.  I've tried `app.method` which doesn't give problems, but doesnt work.  I've tried `thing.method`, throws an error.  I've tried `app.main.thing.method` which does nothing.

I've had success in this same test suite mocking an object and one of its methods, but that object is created and used directly in the server.py file.  I'm wondering if it's because the method being called is so far down the chain.  Mocking is pretty magical to me, especially in Python.

Comment: It's not in a class, it's in the `thing.py` module in my example above.

Answer (score 4):

After more digging finally figured it out, will leave it up for any others that have problems (especially since it's not easily Google'able).

As @Gang specified the full path should work, however the module needs to be the module where the method is called, not the module where it is located, [as this person points out.](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/) . Using @Gang example:

```
@mock.patch('app.main.route.method')
def test(self, mock_method):
    mock_method.return_value = 'foo'
    # call and assert
```